# How big a difference is a 0.25mm thread pitch on a bolt?

Tags: brake-calipers, fastener, bolts, caliper

I've ordered 2 new caliper carrier bolts but they won't arrive today as I needed. I've found a high tensile steel bolt of the same length and width but a difference of 0.25mm thread pitch and yes it's not an automotive bolt but I guess a general or construction bolt.

I'm confident they will screw in (maybe not though) could I get away with using these for a days or two light usage in the car or would they just not fit?

I know it's not ideal and when proper bolts arrive they will be swapped out, so in about 4 days time.

Comment: Apart from the issue of destroying the parts (as stated in the answer) there is no such thing as "light usage" of car brakes - unless you prefer killing somebody to making an emergency stop, of course.

Answer (score 1):

They won't fit! If, say, it's 1.25 instead of 1mm, you'll be trying to match 4 turns on the bolt to 5 on the caliper.

I strongly recommend you don't try, as you could very easily trash the threads on the caliper, and then it's helicoil or new caliper time!

Comment: I see head bolts come in M12, 1.5mm pitch, could I cut these down and use them, they should also be high grade steel?

Comment: @AndyS - Wait for the new bolts or you'll be waiting longer for other new parts, costing you not only more time, but heaps more money.